# AngularJS Custom filter is not triggering on click event

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to filter my table data after selecting conditions from the dropdown. So i have written a angularJS custom filter and passed the parameters required. So if no conditions are selected then whole data should be displayed else filtered data should be displayed. But the filter is not triggering after selecting the condition. Help me with this.

Comment: why you are mixing angular with jquery?

Comment: @pankajparkar it is just a trial. Will move it into directive or somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few errors. The most evident is accessing the dom i a controller. This should be in a directive instead. I created a plunker from your code and moved it to a directive. The filters are not working, but you can catch up from there.

The problem with the filter was that you was passing the customerList twice. So itshould looks like:

```
<tr ng-repeat="customer in (customerList | filterGridData:ctrl.filterCriteria)">
```

See the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/jPJplDAi31Ei7vOIOZIZ?)

Comment: I think customerList is not accessible in the controller. That's why its not being displayed in the table even after getting response of list.json.

Comment: The filter logic is not working because it always returns an empty array. But this was not the question.